# C# - How to create an immutable object with LINQ to Objects

Tags: c#, xml, linq, immutability

I'm creating an object with LINQ by parsing values from an XDocument. It is my understanding that objects should be created to be immutable unless you really need to change the values later on, so I've made private setters.

```
public class GeoLookupResult
{
    public string LocationType { get; private set; }
    public string Country { get; private set; }
    public string CountryIso3166 { get; private set; }

    public GeoLookupResult(string locationType, string country, string countryIso3166)
    {
        this.LocationType = locationType;
        this.Country = country;
        this.CountryIso3166 = countryIso3166;
    }
}
```

But then it seems I can't use LINQ to Objects to create an object with constructors like this (because "GeoLookupResult does not contain a definition for 'locationType'" etc.):

```
XDocument document;

document = XDocument.Load("http://api.wunderground.com/api/d36f54198ebbb48c/geolookup/q/England/London.xml");

var query = from i in document.Descendants("response")
select new GeoLookupResult
{
    locationType = (string)i.Element("location").Element("type"),
    country = (string)i.Element("location").Element("country"),
    countryIso3166 = (string)i.Element("location").Element("country_iso3166")
};
```

Is there a way that I can use the constructors like this? Or should I scratch the idea of immutability and just have public property setters and use those within the LINQ query? (EG: `LocationType = (string)i.Element("location").Element("type")`

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely sure if I get your question correct, but have you tried this?

```
var query = from i in document.Descendants("response")
                select new GeoLookupResult(
                    (string)i.Element("location").Element("type"),
                    (string)i.Element("location").Element("country"),
                     (string)i.Element("country_iso3166")
                );
```

This way you would be calling your defined constructor of the `GeoLookupResult` class with three parameters. The way you currently have it, it is trying to call the default constructor and then assign the provided properties via their setters, which you declared as private.

Comment: Hi, this works thanks. I wasn't aware it was possible to use contructors that way within a query.

Comment: If this answer helped solving your problem, please consider to mark it as the accepted answer (green tick to the left of it). thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use your own constructor. In your linq select statement what you've used is called `Object Initializer` the one with `new GeoLookupResult{..}`. It is mostly used when you don't want to force the object initialization of a class with a constructor.

So Instead of the `Object Initializer` you should call your own constructor.

```
var query = from i in document.Descendants("response")
select new GeoLookupResult( 
    (string)i.Element("location").Element("type"),
    (string)i.Element("location").Element("country"),
    (string)i.Element("country_iso3166")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have mentioned as a constructor is not an OOP constructor but it's an object initialization mechanism (a C# compiler syntactic sugar) that facilitate populating public properties and fields of an object.
If you insist to keep your object immutable you should use a constructor / factory method to let other components create your object.